# How is stored the result of the invokedynamic?

Tags: jvm, java-8, invokedynamic

Java 8 introduces support for first-class functions, which allows assigning functions to variables. In this case the variables must be of a **function type**, which is defined by a **functional interface** (an interface with just one abstract method).

So, considering an example of an interface `I` and a class `A` with the following definition:

```
interface I{ int foo(); }
class A implements I{ 
  public int foo(){return 7;} 
  public static int bar(){return 11;}
}
```

We can assign to a variable of type `I` an instance of `A` or a **method reference** to the method `bar` of `A`. Both can be store on variables of type `I`,  such as:

```
I i1 = new A(); 
I i2 = A::bar;
```

If we analyze the bytecodes resulting from the compilation of the previous code we will get:

```
0: new           #2                  // class A
3: dup
4: invokespecial #3                  // Method A."<init>":()V
7: astore_1
8: invokedynamic #4,  0              // InvokeDynamic #0:foo:()LI;
13: astore_2
```

For `i1 = new A();` that is clearly that the corresponding instruction `7: astore_1` is storing an instance of `A` that is compatible with `I`. But, as a result of the `i2 = A::bar` we are storing the result of the `8: invokedynamic #4,  0`.

So, that means that the result of an `invokedynamic` is always an instance of the **target type**, which is the type of the variable that we are assigning with a method reference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each `invokedynamic` bytecode refers to a corresponding [CONSTANT_InvokeDynamic_info](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.10) structure in the constant pool. This structure contains a [Method Descriptor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.3.3) that is used to derive the types of the arguments and the type of return value for this `invokedynamic` instruction.

In your example the method descriptor is `()LI;` computed during source-to-bytecode translation.

```
8: invokedynamic #4,  0              // InvokeDynamic #0:foo:()LI;
                                                             ^^^^^
```

It means that this particular bytecode expects no arguments and always produces the result of type `I`.

Answer (score 4):

The result of the `invokedynamic` instruction, the way Java 8’s lambda expressions and method references use it, is indeed an instance of the target functional `interface`.

It isn’t the result of the `invokedynamic` instruction that is remembered by the JVM but the `CallSite` that is returned by the bootstrap method, in case of the new Java 8 features one of the two methods of the [`LambdaMetafactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html).

The `CallSite` instances linked to an `invokedynamic` instruction encapsulate *behavior*, not a particular result value. The actual behavior provided by the `LambdaMetafactory` is intentionally unspecified to provide a wide degree of freedom but the current implementation exhibits two different behaviors.

For non-capturing lambda expressions, the behavior will be to return a single instance which has been created during the `invokedynamic` bootstrapping. This can be done by creating a [constant wrapping `MethodHandle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.html#constant-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object-) wrapped in a [`ConstantCallSite`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/ConstantCallSite.html). In this case, subsequent executions of the `invokedynamic` instruction will evaluate to this instance.

For lambda expressions which capture values, the instruction will be linked against a constructor or factory method of a generated class which accepts the captured values. So then, subsequent executions of the `invokedynamic` instruction will behave like an ordinary object construction (which creates a new instance of the class which implements the target `interface` each time).